# P and SPAN are not detected by DOM

Tags: php, dom

I am writing a code to automatically translate html files with DOM and I can not get text elements like P or SPAN. This is my PHP code:

```
<?php

    $fname="t1.html";
    parse_file($fname);


function process_element($elt) {

    echo "name=".$elt->nodeName." type=".$elt->nodeType."\n";
    echo "val='".$elt->nodeValue."'\n";
    echo "text_content='".$elt->textContent."'\n";
    if (!isset($item->childNodes)) return;
    $children = $item->childNodes;
    foreach($children as $child) {
        process_element($child);
    }
}

function parse_file($filename) {


    $document=new DOMDocument();
    $document->load($filename);

    $items=$document->documentElement;
    foreach($items->childNodes as $item) {
        process_element($item);
    }

}
?>
```

This is the sample HTML file I am using:

```
[niko@dev1 www]$ cat t1.html 
<html>
<body>
<p>hello world<br/>
<span>just text</span>
</p>
</body>
</html>
[niko@dev1 www]$
```

And this is why I get as ouptut:

```
[niko@dev1 www]$ php -f p.php 
name=#text type=3
val='
'
text_content='
'
name=body type=1
val='
hello world
just text

'
text_content='
hello world
just text

'
name=#text type=3
val='
'
text_content='
'
[niko@dev1 www]$
```

As you can see, the `<p>` and `<span>` tags are not detected by DOM. Why is that and how can I make DOM to return these elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second half of your `process_element` method suddenly uses an undeclared variable `$item` instead of `$elmt`.
Corrected:

```
function process_element($elt) {
    echo "name=".$elt->nodeName." type=".$elt->nodeType."\n";
    echo "val='".$elt->nodeValue."'\n";
    echo "text_content='".$elt->textContent."'\n";
    if (!isset($elt->childNodes)) return;
    $children = $elt->childNodes;
    foreach($children as $child) {
        process_element($child);
    }
}
```